# It seems the Area 51 proposal close/reopen privilege is no longer enabled. What is the new community guidance for high reputation Area 51 users?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, area-51, privileges, vote-to-reopen

I just noticed that the vote to close and vote to reopen privileges no longer exists on Area 51.  The last community closure was [this "humour" proposal, completed on April 15th](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67651/humour), just seven days earlier.

Upon looking at the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), the close/reopen proposal privilege, once awarded at 2,000 reputation, is no longer listed in the FAQ.

What was the reason for removing these privileges?  What should high reputation Area 51 users be doing instead on Area 51?  How will the removal of the close/reopen privileges help Area 51 in the long run?

Comment: I was told in chat by an A51 regular that the close-voting had gotten so abusive that it was eventually removed.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, @Mysticial. But I've actually seen proposals be given a second chance with 5 reopen votes. Just wondering what the official response is.  It's a long way to 10,000 reputation on Area 51. ;)

Comment: related? http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/14140/where-did-the-close-link-go